# Selenium not visible exeception

Tags: python, selenium

```
<div class="modal  left  fade" id="sidebar_left" tabindex="1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="sidebar_left">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close go-left" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="close icon-angle-left"></i></span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title go-text-right" id="sidebar_left"><i class="icon_set_1_icon-65 go-right"></i> Settings</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-side navbar-right sidebar go-left">
    <li id="li_myaccount">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle go-text-right"><i class="icon_set_1_icon-70 go-right"></i> My Account <b class="lightcaret mt-2 go-left"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="go-text-right" href="a.html"> Login</a></li>
        <li><a class="go-text-right" href="b.html">  Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <div class="header-brdr pull-left hidden-xs hidden-md go-left"></div>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle go-text-right" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <strong><i class="icon-money-2 go-right"></i> 
                USD                </strong>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu wow fadeIn">
```

**I am trying to click the a.html but every time I got an ElementNotVisibleException**

I am using the following line to do the job. Any suggestions ..

elem=driver.find_element_by_id('li_myaccount').click()

Comment: Which element are you trying to click exactly?

Comment: I am trying to click "a.html"

Comment: Fixed It .. Thank You though..